# Quickstart: Create a function in Azure with Python using Visual Studio Code - stuck on step 1

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy a ML model I've developed in Python as an Azure function.

For that, I'm following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) since I know close to nothing related with Azure functions.

After creating the local project, and upon following the instructions on step 1 of "Run the function locally":

> To start the function locally, press F5 or the play icon. The Terminal
> panel displays the Output from Core Tools.

**When doing this, nothing happens.**

According to the tutorial, I should see the URL endpoint of my HTTP-triggered function running locally as per below image from the tutorial:

[image]

Therefore, I'm stuck again!

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

I'm launching VsCode from Anaconda, through a virtual environment (novo).

This is the code of **init**.py:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Comment: You got the URL i.e., `http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample` - copy it and paste it into your browser, you can see the result and it will as you name parameter where you should pass like `http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample?name=unstuck`, then you'll see the output message.

Comment: The 2nd image is from the tutorial. The 1st image is what I've got.

Comment: try running the command `func host start` or `func start` in the IDE terminal and check.

Comment: [2022-08-26T16:04:39.023Z] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
[2022-08-26T16:04:39.591Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'ef6fadf6-451e-473b-b803-f5a77a1eac91'.
[2022-08-26T16:04:39.593Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: Have you installed all the tools required for the Azure Functions project like python runtime, azure functions core tools, etc.

Comment: I did, by following the tutorial.

Comment: also the dotnet sdk and runtime installed?

Comment: No, not that one. I'm trying it here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.400-windows-x64-installer

Comment: Yes, the error seems to be for dotnet sdk & runtime missing. so download, install, restart the IDE and check running the function.

Comment: Restarted windows, func host start now returns: [2022-08-26T16:16:35.046Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'cfa19a82-a4ab-4d08-b627-418d0e742fab'.
[2022-08-26T16:16:35.048Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247589/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-unstuck).

Comment: are you running any spyder/anaconda module in the Azure functions project that I have seen you removed it from the question. could you update us did you installed any anaconda modules after creating the function!

Comment: I tried both running vscode directly and by launching it from anaconda, using an environment. You may see my edit above. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required things to be installed for running the Python Azure Function in VS Code locally are:

1. Python Stable Version (3.x)
2. Azure Functions Core Tools Latest Version.
3. Latest VS Code IDE
4. Extensions in VS Code IDE like Azurite, Python, Azure Account, Azure Functions, Azure Tools, Azure Application Insights.
5. To run the Azure Functions locally, need Azure Storage Emulator.

When coming to the specific errors like

> 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable

It seems to be dotnet is not included in the System Environment Variables Path. Download .NET Core 6 SDK + Runtime and Check the installed path is added to the Environment Variables:

- In the Command Prompt, run `dotnet --version`
- Windows Search  Button > Search for Environment Variables > Open & Click ️ on Environment Variables >

[image]

Below code copied from my VS Code Azure Functions Python project:

**requirements.txt** :

```
azure-functions
```

**local.settings.json**:

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
}
}
```

host.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
    }
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
    }
}
```

**function.json**:

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"authLevel": "anonymous",
"type": "httpTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"name": "req",
"methods": [
"get","post"
]
},
{
"type": "http",
"direction": "out",
"name": "$return"
}
]
}
```

- Make Sure the Azure Storage Emulator is running in your system so that the host errors will not occurs when running the function/trigger or you can start it manually using the below command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
```

[image: azfvscodepythoncreation]

[image: azfvscodepythonrun]

Comment: Hi, in cmd dotnet --version returns: It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download. It's funny, because I have already installed it!

Comment: I have actually started the whole thing again from scratch. Created a new project, a new folder, and I got exactly the same error! "The system can't locate the specified path"

Answer (score 1):

I followed the tutorial, and it worked for me:

Creating Python AZ Function and Debugin

[image]

Look like you are having a problem with something that changed location.
How did you start? did you launch VS Code with File>New Window? When you click the "+" besides "workspace" and create a new function, did you click "create new project" and selected a folder? It seems something got lost/corrupted during that but could also be the version of your VS code. I would suggest you make sure you have the latest VS Code, the latest version of the "Azure Functions" add-on:

Azure function Add-on for VS Code
[image]

1. Some of the above components may be corrupted, and you need to uninstall and install them again
2. Did you follow this steps that create the files/folders and opened it correctly:

Steps
[image]

Trust check
[image]

Comment: Hello Bruno! Yes, it seems there's a problem with the path. Please see my edit above. Shall I just delete the whole thing and start over again?

Comment: You can try starting over with a new project. Case still doesn't work; it may be you have something on your Environment Path confusing VS Code.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling anaconda, and installing it back again, created a new environment, a new project, and nothing! the whole fxx weekend with this